# C# Semaphore Check Race Condition

Tags: c#, multithreading, race-condition

I'm using a SemaphoreLite to ensure that all events that fire and error are written out to a special file. The problem is a background thread calls close before the writing is done and since the semaphore says its empty for a split second it disposes the semaphore cause the write to be incomplete.

Here is my code:

```
    private void waitForWriterErrorEventsToFire()
    {
        //TODO: Figure out a way to avoid race conditions
        if (_notProcessedCount == null)
        {
            return;
        };

        while (_notProcessedCount.CurrentCount != int.MaxValue)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(500);
        if (_notProcessedCount.CurrentCount != int.MaxValue)
        {
            waitForWriterErrorEventsToFire();
        }
        _notProcessedCount.Dispose();
        _notProcessedCount = null;
    }
```

The Thread.Sleep(500) fixes the problem for the most part, but that is not the correct thing to do. I know the race condition happens on the while loop condition, Current counts return int.MaxValue, but if you check it again after the sleep it is now less than int.MaxValue. Any suggestion on how to avoid the race condition?

I was thinking of coding something up that does that check for a set time and after that pass if the condition still holds then dispose.

Comment: What is your goal with this semaphore? Is it just to output to a file?

Comment: Check the semaphore count only within the context of a lock?

Comment: tried the lock, but after you unlock an event is fired on another thread that causes the count to decrease in the semaphore, but its already disposed of the semaphore